# Ubuntu 20.04 from MS Store on Windows does not start after reboot

Tags: kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL Ubuntu 20.04 from Microsoft Install following all the steps properly from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 official documentation.

I also passed the following commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

on Ubuntu terminal. It installed the necessary package.

I passed `wsl -l -v` on cmd and it showed me the required information.

However, I later restarted my PC and now Ubuntu terminal is not working. It's showing,

> Installing, this may take few minutes...

and hangs there.

I tried

```
wsl -l -v
```

and

```
wsl --list --version
```

but neither works.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is AskUbuntu for Ubuntu OS issues, since you are on Windows 10 I would switch this question to the Windows section.

Comment: @SimpliFixed WSL is explicitly on topic here and that includes installation in Windows, so while this post might be more likely to get answered on [SU], it's fine here.